# How do you test react state in functional component using jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I have a functional component called `StoreLocator` and want to test if its state will change or not?

I know if `StoreLocator` was a `class` component I could test it this way using `instance` method:

```
describe('chooseMap', () => {
  it('updates currentMap using location passed to it', () => {
    const mountedStoreLocator = shallow(<StoreLocator />);
    const mockEvent = 'testland.png';
    mountedStoreLocator.instance().chooseMap(mockEvent);
    expect(mountedStoreLocator.instance().state.currentMap).toBe('testland.png');
  })
})
```

but when I try below code to achieve the same thing in functional component and hook it doesn't work:

```
describe('chooseMap', () => {
  it('updates currentMap using location passed to it', () => {
    const mountedStoreLocator = shallow(<StoreLocator />);
    const mockEvent = 'testland.png';
    mountedStoreLocator.chooseMap(mockEvent);
    expect(mountedStoreLocator.currentMap).toBe('testland.png');
  })
})
```

and it says `TypeError: mountedStoreLocator.chooseMap is not a function`

here is the `StoreLocator` Component:

```
export default function StoreLocator({location}) {
  const [currentMap, setCurrentMap] = useState('none.png');

    const shops = [
        {
            location: "Portland",
            address: "123 Portland Dr",
        },
        {
            location: "Astoria",
            address: "123 Astoria Dr",
        },
        {
            location: "",
            address: "",
        },
  ];
  
  const chooseMap = (location) => {
    setCurrentMap(location);
  }
  
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div>
                {shops.map((shop, index) => (
                    <Button handleClick={chooseMap} location={shop.location} key={index} />
                ))}
            </div>
            <Map imageName={currentMap} location={location} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

`EDIT`

---

I've tested like below as @RafaelTavares mentioned in comment:

```
describe('change image correctly', () => {
    it('should call handleClick on button click', () => {
        const mountedStoreLocator = shallow(<StoreLocator />);
        const map = mountedStoreLocator.find('Map');
        expect(map.prop('imageName')).toBe('none.png');
        const astoriaBtn = mountedStoreLocator.find('Button[location="Astoria"]');
        astoriaBtn.invoke('handleClick')('Astoria');
        expect(map.prop('imageName')).toBe('Astoria');
        expect(astoriaBtn.length).toBe(1);
    })
})
```

but still no luck and my test will fail by this message:

```
Expected: "Astoria"

Received: "none.png"
```

Comment: You don't; the state of a component is internal to it, it's an implementation detail. Test components via their public API: props and the DOM.

Comment: So you're saying there is no way to test state in functional Component?

Comment: To "test the state" you should simulate a click in the button and then check the `Map` `imageName` prop. Doing it you are testing the behavior, not the implementation detail as jonrsharpe pointed out.

Comment: Thanks @RafaelTavares , I've `Edited` the answer and tried your suggestion but still no luck